# Finding next perfect square

Tags: python, perfect-square

this code was supposed to find if given input is perfect square and to return next perfect square

eg n=121-->144

but I don't know why it is not working

### To find next perfect square

```
from math import sqrt,pow

def perfect_sqr( n ):
    if n%n**0.5==0:
return pow((sqrt(n)+1),2)
perfect_sqr(121)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just add a print in front of your function call, "print perfect_sqr(121)", also please indent the return statement.

Comment: Why not take the square root of `n`, then find the ceiling (round up), then square that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation seems incorrect.  Maybe just how you formatted it here?  Also, taking pmaniyan's suggestion to add a print statement

```
from math import sqrt,pow

def perfect_sqr( n ):
    if n%n**0.5==0:
        return pow((sqrt(n)+1),2)
print(perfect_sqr(144))
```

Produces the desired behavior for me.  Function returns `None` if `n` is not a perfect square.

For Python 2.7, use `print perfect_sqr(144)`

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer was what you needed, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer to your question?